# Creating multiple generic types (tuples) with different parameters

Tags: c#, .net

So suppose that I have an list called "arr." I want to move all of the contents from the list into an AVLTree that takes a tuple as the key of its (key, value) pair. I do not know how big the tuple will be before runtime (1-tuple, 2-tuple, 3-tuple, etc.); this is determined by the length of the `String[]` "keyOrder".

I was thinking of trying to use `Type` to generate the different generic types and then using `Activator` to instantiate a tuple from one of those types. If that is the right way to do it, how would one do it efficiently? If there's a better way to do do it, then could someone please enlighten me?

```
private List<IQueryable> arr { get; }
private AVLTree<IComparable, int> avlTree;
private String[] keyOrder;

public ListTable(List<IQueryable> arr, String[] keyOrder) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.keyOrder = keyOrder;
}

private void createAVLTree() {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i) {
        avlTree.Insert(/*some 1-tuple, 2-tuple, 3-tuple, etc. definition*/, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a custom class the the String[] as a property.  Then make the class IComparable with a CompareTo() method.  You can add code in the CompareTo() to handle multiple size arrays.  the custom class will be the key in your dictionary.